# URL over-writing during every click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried `history.pushState` function to change my URL in the address bar on link click...

Everything went right.

But instead of showing different URL every time as per my desire, it started overwriting.

Here are my codes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#followers').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    data = 'page1';
    url = 'followers/';
    history.pushState(data, null, url);
    document.title = 'Followers | <?php echo VISIT_FIRSTNAME;?> <?php echo VISIT_LASTNAME;?> (@<?php echo VISIT_USERNAME; ?>) | <?php echo SITE_NAME; ?>';
    $('#data').load('/auth/load/load_followers', {
      'username': '<?php echo VISIT_USERNAME; ?>',
      'visit_id': '<?php echo VISIT_ID; ?>'
    });
  });
  $('#following').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    data = 'page1';
    url = 'following/';
    history.pushState(data, null, url);
    document.title = 'Following | <?php echo VISIT_FIRSTNAME;?> <?php echo VISIT_LASTNAME;?> (@<?php echo VISIT_USERNAME; ?>) | <?php echo SITE_NAME; ?>';
    $('#data').load('/auth/load/load_followings', {
      'username': '<?php echo VISIT_USERNAME; ?>',
      'visit_id': '<?php echo VISIT_ID; ?>'
    });
  });
  $('#message').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    data = 'page1';
    url = 'message/';
    history.pushState(data, null, url);
    document.title = 'Message | <?php echo VISIT_FIRSTNAME;?> <?php echo VISIT_LASTNAME;?> (@<?php echo VISIT_USERNAME; ?>) | <?php echo SITE_NAME; ?>';
    $('#data').load('/auth/load/load_message', {
      'username': '<?php echo VISIT_USERNAME; ?>'
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that it's appending the URL instead of overwriting?

Comment: Relevance of php tag to this question?

Comment: If you want to replace the URL, remove the last slash: `message`, `followers` and so on. If  they end with a slash, then it will append the new URL to the existing instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How `history.pushState` works is:
If you pass the `url` params as

`history.pushState('page1', null, 'follower/')`

`history.pushState('page1', null, 'following/')`

`history.pushState('page1', null, 'messages/')`

You will end up concatenating them like: 'follower/following/messages'.

I am assuming from you question, what you need is instead.

`history.pushState('page1', null, 'follower')`

`history.pushState('page1', null, 'following')`

`history.pushState('page1', null, 'messages')`

Remove the trailing `/`, It will overwrite instead of concatenate.

Comment: Basically, the rule seems to be that these formats: `new-url`, `/new-url` and `/new-url/` all replaces the URL while `new-url/` appends it to the URL.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson true.

Comment: @nitte93user3232918 thanks, alot .... it wasted my last two days to resolve this.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks to you also for your valuable response.